# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to vuejs, While writing one js code inside laravel framework, I am getting error :

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

**App.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vcinfo from './Vcinfo.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vcinfo',
    components: { Vcinfo },
    template: '<app></app>',
    router
})
```

please suggest what to do?

Comment: Your template contains `<app></app>`, but you do not import a component called `app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for future reader.
I made the mistake I had to use it like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vcinfo from './Vcinfo.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vcinfo',
    components: { Vcinfo },
    template: '<vcinfo></vcinfo>',
    router
})
```

as per this import `import Vcinfo from './Vcinfo.vue'`